# Javascript character encoding in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, character-encoding

I have a script that compares an array of strings in Hebrew to some Hebrew text on the website. The script works correctly in all browsers except for some versions of Internet Explorer. The only way I have to to debug it is to log the browser user agent however when I try to reproduce the issue in the same IE version, everything seems to work correctly on my local machine.

The relevant part of the script

```
var cities = ['אילת','ים המלח','תל אביב','באר שבע','חיפה','נתניה'];
if (pids.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        if (pids[0].search(cities[i]) > -1){
            userinfo.city = cities[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    //for debugging
    if (userinfo.city =='') log += navigator.userAgent;
}
```

I know that pids has the right value because all the other information the script collects is handled correctly. The problem is only in this string search.

Here's a sample of user agents that are logged:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; BRI/2)

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; McAfee; rv:11.0) like Gecko

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Tablet PC 2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Edit: I realize I didn't adequately explain what happens when the script fails. When the script fails userinfo.city is empty. This cannot happen in practice because pids[0] will always have one of the values in it.

The value in pids[0] is retrieved by scraping from the DOM. The value it contains is correct because it's used in other parts of the program which work correctly.

The `document.characterSet` of the site where this script runs is utf-8

The script is encoded in utf-8 and is loaded via google tag manager.

Comment: Please explain in detail what happens when the script does not work correctly. Which result do you want, which one do you get? Also is the script code part of an HTML document or part of a separate .js file? Which encodings do the files have?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I added more information to the post, I hope it's clearer.

Comment: Can't you use the built-in debugger available in IE (press F12)? Or the problem is just happening in old IEs?

Comment: @Prusse the problem doesn't happen to me locally when I test it in IE